# bestscore in python Idle

Tags: python

I have a game that I made instead of wanting a highscore function I would like a lowscore function.

I have not seen a working lowscore function so far so I have tried to create my own but I'm a fairly new programmer

```
def reaction():
    import time
    import sys
    print("Split second reaction")
    print("*********************")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Ready")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Set")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Go!")
    start = time.time()
    g=input()
    end = time.time()
    score=end - start
    highscore=open("record is in this document:")
    if score<highscore:
       print("New Highscore! "))
       highscore=score
    else:
       print("Highscore:",highscore)

reaction()
```

Comment: What is your output?

Comment: notepad document with the record number

Comment: What do you see happening, what do you want to happen?

Comment: You are setting`record` but showing `highscore` - you might want to investigate that

Comment: when highscore is beaten highscore replaced

Comment: dank u hans however it is coming up with

Comment: (Unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated\UXXXXXXXX escape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a better score is found, that is score < record, you should save the result in the same file. See code below:

```
def reaction():
    import time
    import sys
    print("Split second reaction")
    print("*********************")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Ready")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Set")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Go!")
    start = time.time()
    g=input()
    end = time.time()
    score=end - start
    with open("data.txt") as file:
       highscore = float(file.readline())
    if score<highscore:
       with open("data.txt", "w") as file:
         file.write(str(score))
         print("New Highscore! ")
    else:
       print("Highscore:",highscore)

reaction()
```

Comment: how would I do that

Comment: you will need to have a file named data.txt in the same location you have the .py file. The data.txt file should also have a number in it